# Items in function become nil when function is called - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom class segmented control that is communicating with a view controller every time a different item in the segmented control is selected. I'm able to pass data to the view controller just fine.

```
@IBDesignable class SegmentedControlLeft: UIControl {

    var selectedIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            displayNewSelectedIndex()
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let messagesViewController: MessagesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PurpleVC") as! MessagesViewController
            messagesViewController.animateViews(selectedIndex: selectedIndex)
        }
    }
...some more code
}
```

However, when I try to use some basic logic every time the passed variable is updated, all the items inside the "animateViews" function apparently turn nil. I receive the infamous "unexpectedly found nil" error. This only happens when i try to use the variable I'm passing, everything runs as expected otherwise outside of the function.

```
import UIKit

class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var messageTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var boostCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
            ...all cells, delegates, and datasource are registered and setup in here.
        }

        func animateViews(selectedIndex: Int) {

                if selectedIndex == 0 {
                    print("LEFT")  // prints as expected
                    self.messagesTableView.isHidden = false  // unexpected found nil error on each of these items.
                    self.boostCollectionView.isHidden = true
                } else if selectedIndex == 1 {
                    print("RIGHT") // prints correctly when updated
                    self.messageTableView.isHidden = true
                    self.boostCollectionView.isHidden = false
                }
            } 
}
```

I've been playing around with this for far too long, **how do I get views in the animateViews function to hide and unhide using the variable I'm passing from the segmented Control?**

There is probably an amazingly simple fix that I'm not getting here, but I appreciate you for getting your eyeballs this far. Thank you!

Comment: Why would someone down-vote this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because by the time you call
 `messagesViewController.animateViews(selectedIndex: selectedIndex)`, the `MessagesViewController` is not instantiated. That also means that the Table view and Collection View are not drawn yet and you are trying to use it before it is being created.

The `viewDidLoad()` method has to be called once to use the UI Elements of the View Controller.

Each time this line is called `let messagesViewController: MessagesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControl`, a new instance of the view controller is created.

**Suggestion:**

My suggestion will be to create an outlet of the segmented controls(seems like you are having multiple Segmented Controls in View Controller), and create a method like `@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {` and assign this action to the `value changed` property of the segmented controls.

You can differentiate among the segmented controls using the `sender` parameter.

Comment: Success! Your explanations and suggestions were fantastic! Everything now works perfectly. Thank you for the valueable insight!